# after parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: C

Tags: c#, json

i am trying to Deserialize JSON Data below is structure of json data

```
[{"empcode":"e123","joining_date":"2017-10-31T00:00:00","pfno":"pf232323","Rating":"A","emp_Type":"full","Project_name":"abcd 123bcc  "C""}]
```

Project_name consist of double quotes character inside json

i am using newtonsoft.json for Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data

when i Deserialize JSON Data to datatable it gives error after parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: C.

```
 public static datatable getDataFromServer(string url)
    {

        HttpWebRequest req = null;
        HttpWebResponse res = null;

        //string url = url1 + date;
        //Console.WriteLine(url);
        req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";


        // req = AddProxy(req);



        res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = res.GetResponseStream();
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        string txt = streamReader.ReadToEnd();



          txt = txt.Replace("\\", "").Replace("/", "");
       // txt = txt.Replace("\\", "");
       // txt = txt.Replace(@"\", "");
            txt = txt.Remove(0, 1);
          txt = txt.Remove(txt.Length - 1, 1);

         DataTable ds = GetDeserializedFrmJson(txt);
        streamReader.Close();
        streamReader.Dispose();

        responseStream.Close();
        responseStream.Dispose();

        return ds;


    }




 public static DataTable GetDeserializedFrmJson(string data)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, (typeof(DataTable)));
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: Well yes, that's invalid JSON. You've got "C" within a value, without the quotes being escaped. Admittedly that may be because you're manually removing all slashes - why are you doing that? I strongly recommend that you stop messing with the JSON you receive.

Comment: Next, what does `GetDeserializedFrmJson`? Please provide a [mcve] (just hard-code the JSON). If you're not using a JSON parser library to parse the JSON, instead relying on hand-written code, I strongly recommend that you stop doing that immediately.

Comment: using Newtonsoft.Json;

Comment: Is that the raw JSON string you received from the web request or after you've just removed the escaped quotes with `txt = txt.Replace("\\", "")`? That is maybe not a good idea. Because `"abcd 123bcc  \"C\""` should be a valid JSON string, yours is not.

Answer (score 1):

> i am trying to Deserialize JSON Data below is structure of json data

No it's not. That's no valid JSON. The error is exactly what it said it was, there are quotes that are not escaped properly, so you have a dangling "C" that is not valid JSON.

I don't know what to tell you. Your code might be fine (didn't look at it), you need to fix your data so it's valid JSON.